# Get the time taken by executing cmd command in java

Tags: java, cmd

how i can get the time taken by a certain cmd command  called from java
suppose i am issuing icmp request

```
String icmpRequest= "ping 192.168.3.3";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(icmpRequest);
```

after the exec is called my function will  complete to the next line.
is there a way to know the time consumed by execution of this command or to stop this thread until this process is finished.

can we say that the process is finished after the inputstream of the process return data

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            //reads the outputs
            String inputLine = in.readLine();
            if(inpuLine!=null)
             System.out.println("process finished");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` returns a `Process` which you can use:

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(icmpRequest); 
p.waitFor();
long end = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("it took: " + ((end - start) / 1000000) + "ms");
```

Note: if you want to continue doing other things while the process completes, you can call it from a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Log `System.currentTimeMillis()` (which returns the current time in milliseconds) as the last thing before executing your process. Subtract as soon as the process ends.

```
String icmpRequest= "ping 192.168.3.3";

long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(icmpRequest); 
p.waitFor();

System.out.println("Took " + (start - System.currentTimeMillis()) + " ms");
```

`Process.waitFor()` causes the current thread to wait until the child process has terminated.